# Shopping Cart with multiple orders in ASP

Tags: c#, asp.net, shopping-cart

I'm building an e-commerce website in ASP.Net/C# and I'm having some difficulties with my shopping cart...

I want my costumers to be able to say "I want **X** boxes, and each box carries **Y** items".

Let's say, for instance, my website sells flowers. A client logs in and then chooses **X** **bouquets** and then for **each bouquet** he **adds flowers from the catalog**.

Can you point me out some links or tips in order to achieve this behaviour?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you think about it, this is a little like those applications where you put a laptop in your basket, and then customize it. But instead you put a bouquet in your basket, and customize it!

We've been doing something similar (food related) having found this demo...

http://demo.kartris.com/Spotpal-1800-SA/p-10/

We've modified it instead so we have our base food item as the laptop, and then the add ons are done in the same way as memory processor etc.

Answer (score 1):

A simple class hierarchy might be:

*Order* has *ItemContainers* has *Items*

Both ItemContainers and Items would have a quantity.

Kindness,

Dan

Answer (score 1):

simple ask user to select a bouquets then display a list of flowers with checkboxes and store the checked number of boxes in session with their ids as well as the bouquets.
the final cart table  will have flower id, bouquets id and flower count
and you can associate this relation by asking him to create a bouquets and then add flowers to it